# Android SQLite error: Inserting data

Tags: android, sqlite

I my application crashes whenever I try and access data in my database. I am suspecting that I am not inserting the data correctly into the database, down below are the classes and methods I use.

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_QUICK_STOP = "quick_stop";

    public static String[] QUICK_STOP_FIELDS = {
        "_id", // autoincrement
        "quick_stop_stop_id", // stop id
        "quick_stop_name",
        "quick_stop_types", // ex. 1111 or 0101. Underground Train Bus Ferry, used to filter some specific stations
        "quick_stop_position"
        //TODO should there be a "stop_name" here?
    };

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_QUICK_STOP + "("
        + QUICK_STOP_FIELDS[0] + " long primary key, " // id (same stop can be added multiple times with different filters)
        + QUICK_STOP_FIELDS[1] + " integer not null, " // stop id
        + QUICK_STOP_FIELDS[2] + " varchar not null, " // stop name
        + QUICK_STOP_FIELDS[3] + " integer not null, " // stop types
        + QUICK_STOP_FIELDS[4] + " integer not null);"; // stop position            array[4] = cursor.getInt(4); // stop position

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUICK_STOP);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

And I use this to insert:

```
public Boolean insertStop(int stopId, String name, int types, int position) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.QUICK_STOP_FIELDS[1], stopId);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.QUICK_STOP_FIELDS[2], name);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.QUICK_STOP_FIELDS[3], types);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.QUICK_STOP_FIELDS[4], position);
    long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_QUICK_STOP, null, values);
    if(insertId == -1)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

As stated, Android Studio is horrible at giving information to be able to debug.

Comment: Did you **alter** the table structure after the first run? If so, change `DATABASE_VERSION = 1;` to `DATABASE_VERSION = 2;` or a higher number, in order to make `onUpgrade()` fire. Or try removing the db from the `/data/data/...` path in order for it to be re-created on next run.

Comment: @DerGolem I changed the database name and it worked, so you are correct in your comment. State it as an answer and I will accept!

Comment: Done! Sometimes errors hide in plain sight...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you **alter** the table structure after the first run?

If so, change DATABASE_VERSION = 1; to DATABASE_VERSION = 2; or a higher number, in order to make onUpgrade() fire.

Or, as an alternative, try removing (or renaming) the db from the `/data/data/...` path in order for it to be re-created on next run.